# Consulta como actualizar las filas, despues de eliminar

Tags: android-studio

estoy trabajando a través de un tabledlayout en elk cual se elimina la fila que el suario escoga, por ejemplo actualmente poseo 6 filas y elimino la 3 y al momento de refrescar la tabalelayout este me arroja bien que es las filas 1,2,4,5,6 y lo que pretendo hacer es que qude con el 1,2,3,4,5, mira les presento la secuencia completa que se realiza
Punto 1: el usuario escoge la fila y la edita y presiona el botón eliminar:

```
btn_eliminar2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            eliminardatos("http://192.168.1.90/gestion/eliminar_presupuesto2.php");
        }
    });
```

Punto 2: se dirige al private que contiene la URL

```
private void eliminardatos (String URL) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Datos eliminados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            buscar1();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    List<Presupuesto2> updatedDataList = new ArrayList<>();
                    actualizarNumerosFila(updatedDataList);
                }
            }, 3000); // 3000 milisegundos = 3 segundos
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parametros.put("ID", txtid1.getText().toString());
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Punto 3: siguiendo la secuencia se dirige al buscar1():

```
private void buscar1(){
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    tbldatos.removeAllViews();
    String url = "http://192.168.1.90/gestion/buscar_presupuesto5.php?Patente_Vehiculo=" + m.getText().toString();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            tableDynamic.addHeader(header);
            tableDynamic.backgroundHeader(Color.BLUE);
            tableDynamic.backgroundData(Color.RED, Color.YELLOW);
            tableDynamic.lineColor(Color.BLACK);
            tableDynamic.textColorData(Color.WHITE);
            tableDynamic.textColorHeader(Color.MAGENTA);
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    LayoutInflater reg1 = getLayoutInflater();
                    View registro = reg1.inflate(R.layout.tabla4, null, false);
                    colFilas = registro.findViewById(R.id.colFilas);
                    colCantidad = registro.findViewById(R.id.colCantidad);
                    colRepuestos = registro.findViewById(R.id.colRepuestos);
                    colValor = registro.findViewById(R.id.colValor);
                    String id = jsonObject.getString("ID"); // Obtener el valor del campo ID
                    colFilas.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Filas"));
                    colCantidad.setText(jsonObject.getString("Cant_Repuestos"));
                    colRepuestos.setText(jsonObject.getString("Repuestos"));
                    colValor.setText(jsonObject.getString("Valor_Repuestos"));
                    registro.setTag(id); // Guardar el valor de 'id' en el tag de la vista registro
                    tbldatos.addView(registro);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

punto 4: terminando dicho proceso vuelve al punto 2 se dirige al actualizar las filas, el cual es el del problema que no me actualiza las filas en forma visual:

```
private void actualizarNumerosFila(List<Presupuesto2> updatedDataList) {
    int rowCount = tableLayout.getChildCount();

    // Limpiar la lista antes de agregar nuevos elementos
    updatedDataList.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount - 1; i++) { // Restamos 1 para excluir la fila del encabezado
        TableRow row = (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(i + 1); // Sumamos 1 para saltar la fila del encabezado

        // Obtener los datos de la fila
        int cantidad = Integer.parseInt(((TextView) row.getChildAt(1)).getText().toString());
        String repuestos = ((TextView) row.getChildAt(2)).getText().toString();
        int valor = Integer.parseInt(((TextView) row.getChildAt(3)).getText().toString());
        String patente = m.getText().toString();

        // Crear un objeto Presupuesto2 con los datos
        Presupuesto2 item = new Presupuesto2();
        item.setFilas(String.valueOf(i + 1)); // Aquí actualizamos el número de fila correctamente
        item.setCantidad(cantidad);
        item.setRepuesto(repuestos);
        item.setValor(valor);
        item.setPatente(patente);

        // Agregar el objeto a la lista
        updatedDataList.add(item);
    }

    // Finalmente, procedemos a actualizar los datos en el servidor
    actualizartabla(updatedDataList);
}
```

si lo que pretendo hacer es que si tengo 6 filas y elimino la fila 3, cuyo proceso lo realiza bien y después de refrescar la tabledlayout me muestra así la columna N° Filas 1,2,4,5,6 y lo que quiero es que quede con 1,2,3,4,5 eso es lo que quiero hacer en el actualizarfilas, ojala que me puedan ayudar ya que desde el Jueves de la semana pasada que estoy con este problema, he hecho de todo pero no se que más hacer, cualquier otro código o explicación me la hacen saber y desde ya muchas gracias y disculpen las molestias no me gusta molestar mucho a la gente, pero en este caso me veo obligado en hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

muy buenas amigos del foros, para los que recién comienzan en el mundo del android-studio al igual que yo, y al trabajar con el tabledlayout, encontré la solución para que una vez que elimine una fila esta vuelva a contar desde 1 hasta n, es decir en forma correlativa, el proceso es el siguiente, paso1:

```
btn_eliminar2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            eliminardatos("http://192.168.1.89/gestion/eliminar_presupuesto2.php");
        }
    });
```

posteriormente paso 2:

```
private void eliminardatos (String URL) {
    if (cmdingresar.isActivated()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Primero debe realizar la busqueda por la patente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Datos eliminados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            cmdmodificar.setEnabled(false);
            buscar1();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    obtenerDatosActualizados();
                }
            }, 3000); // 3000 milisegundos = 3 segundos
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parametros.put("ID", txtid1.getText().toString());
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

siguiendo con la lógica paso 3:

```
private void buscar1(){
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    tbldatos.removeAllViews();
    String url = "http://192.168.1.89/gestion/buscar_presupuesto5.php?Patente_Vehiculo=" + m.getText().toString();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            tableDynamic.addHeader(header);
            tableDynamic.backgroundHeader(Color.BLUE);
            tableDynamic.backgroundData(Color.RED, Color.YELLOW);
            tableDynamic.lineColor(Color.BLACK);
            tableDynamic.textColorData(Color.WHITE);
            tableDynamic.textColorHeader(Color.MAGENTA);
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    LayoutInflater reg1 = getLayoutInflater();
                    View registro = reg1.inflate(R.layout.tabla4, null, false);
                    colFilas = registro.findViewById(R.id.colFilas);
                    colCantidad = registro.findViewById(R.id.colCantidad);
                    colRepuestos = registro.findViewById(R.id.colRepuestos);
                    colValor = registro.findViewById(R.id.colValor);
                    int id = jsonObject.getInt("ID");
                    colFilas.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Filas"));
                    colCantidad.setText(jsonObject.getString("Cant_Repuestos"));
                    colRepuestos.setText(jsonObject.getString("Repuestos"));
                    colValor.setText(jsonObject.getString("Valor_Repuestos"));
                    registro.setTag(id);
                    tbldatos.addView(registro);
                }
                // Mapa para almacenar el ID asociado al número de fila
                idMap.clear();
                int filaNumero = 1; // Variable para asignar números de fila
                for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);

                    int id = jsonObject.getInt("ID");
                    idMap.put(id, id);

                    // Resto del código para mostrar los datos en la tabla
                    // ...
                    filaNumero++;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

posteriormente el proceso que realiza la actualización de las filas:

```
private void obtenerDatosActualizados() {
    int rowCount = tbldatos.getChildCount();
    updatedDataList.clear(); // Limpiamos la lista antes de actualizarla nuevamente
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount - 1; i++) { // Restamos 1 para excluir la fila del encabezado
        TableRow row = (TableRow) tbldatos.getChildAt(i + 1); // Sumamos 1 para saltar la fila del encabezado
        TextView colFilas = row.findViewById(R.id.colFilas);
        String numeroFila = String.valueOf(i + 1); // Actualizamos el número de fila en la lista
        colFilas.setText(numeroFila); // Actualizamos el número de fila en la tabla
        Presupuesto2 item = new Presupuesto2();
        item.setFilas(numeroFila);
        updatedDataList.add(item);
    }
    int updatedDataListSize = updatedDataList.size();
    if (rowCount < updatedDataListSize) {
        updatedDataList.subList(rowCount, updatedDataListSize).clear();
    }
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            actualizartabla(updatedDataList);
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

en fin este es el proceso que se realizar para realizar la actualización de las filas, además es importante realizar estas declaraciones:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private ArrayList<Presupuesto2> lista = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Presupuesto2> updatedDataList = new ArrayList<>();
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> idMap = new HashMap<>();
```

lo ideal es realizarlo antes del inflater, para que puedan declaralo y aasí funcionar en forma correcta, ojala que les sirva de ayuda, para los que tienen o tuvieron el mismo problema que yo.